# Does keeping a reference to a mysql identifier is trouble shooting?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

My web server run into such errors :

> Server: example.com User: yyy MySQL Connection Limit: Current MySQL Connections: 81

I am investigating on the reasons of this problem.

The PHP manual says :

> [Freeing resources](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php#language.types.resource.self-destruct)
>
> Thanks to the reference-counting system introduced with PHP 4's Zend
>   Engine, a resource with no more references to it is detected
>   automatically, and it is freed by the garbage collector. For this
>   reason, it is rarely necessary to free the memory manually.

So, does keeping a reference to a MySQL identifier could be a problem for website with pages displayed in more than 3 seconds (generally) ?

I manage MySQL connections like that :

1 - I keep a global variable `$LINK` as a reference to the MySQL resource

```
//MySQL connection
$LINK = 0;
function db_connect(){
    //get variables
    global $LINK,$CONF;

    if($LINK == 0){
        $LINK = @mysql_connect($CONF['host'], $CONF['user'], $CONF['password'])){
    }
}
```

2 - I use a function like this one to do queries :

```
function db_query($sql){
    global $LINK,$CONF,$NB_QUERIES,$TEMPS_QUERIES,$queries, $CLOSED;

    if(db_connect()){
        //do some debug stuff if needed

        //execute the query
        $result = @mysql_query($sql,$LINK);

        //do some other debug stuff if needed

        return $result;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Am I looking in the right direction or there are some others things to look at first when having such errors?

Comment: I would toss some debug code inside your `if($LINK...) {` statement like `echo 'connect!';` and run your page. I have a feeling your making a new connection each time you run db_query. If that's the case, you need to find a better way to track your database link.

Comment: thanks for the hint, but `echo 'connect!';` is print only once.

Comment: Maybe closing the connection is worth a try at the end of your index.php for instance mysql_close($LINK);